# Categories are not showing in Admin Product Edit Page Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2

Magento version 2.2.2

Steps to reproduce
Catalog > Product > Add New Product > Categories

Expected Result
List of Category

Actual result
Empty Category

[image]

Comment: I have similar issue but when i refresh the cache  ,it start showing up but after few hours its not showing. Do you have the similar issue and found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This might occur due to Root Category Id, Please have a look to Following case

In Magento, Root Category ID is hardcoded in Class **Magento\Catalog\Model\Category** On **Line Number 58**

```
/**
 * Id of root category
 */
const ROOT_CATEGORY_ID = 0;

/**
 * Id of category tree root
 */
const TREE_ROOT_ID = 1;
```

So make sure you have not deleted Root category if deleted and created new Root category Then you have to Set That category Id in above Class Like your new Root category Id is **3**.

```
/**
 * Id of root category
 */
const ROOT_CATEGORY_ID = 3;

/**
 * Id of category tree root
 */
const TREE_ROOT_ID = 3;
```